# MultiValueDictKeyError at /verification/

Tags: django

I have problem in getting data from FORM tag.

**login.html**

```
<div class="account-wall">
    <img class="profile-img" src={% static "assets/images/umltopython.jpeg"%}"alt="">

    <form class="form-signin" action="{% url "verification" %}" method="POST">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**views.py**

```
def verification(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    #password = request.POST.get('password')

    return HttpResponse(username)
```

**url.py**

```
url(r'^login/$',person.views.login,name="login",),
url(r'^verification/$',person.views.verification,name="verification",),
```

the error is : [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a HTML form gets serialized, it is the `name` attributes of the inputs that are used as keys for their values, not their ids.

For example, `<input id="an_input" name="foo" value="bar">` will be serialized to `foo=bar` which Django will deserialize, [more or less](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects), to a Python `dict`, here: `{'foo': 'var'}`.

All you need to do is:

```
<form class="form-signin" action="{% url "verification" %}" method="POST">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```